# SPFx webpart workbench on localhost is not connecting

Tags: error, spfx, workbench

After creating a new project with SharePoint generator I can not connect to my workbench on localhost (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET) via HTTPS!

I have tried numerous changes in internet settings and in Visual Studio Code, but my localhost (http://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html) is not responding.

Have tried with browsers like IE11, FireFox, Chrome.

Any ideas which settings I have to change?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I had this issue. I tried every possible things and it never worked. I ran this command npm install gulp -g. It started working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*you can avoid your problem by using http instead of https*
To do that, in

```
config\serve.json
```

set

```
"https": false,
```

and remove the "s" from the URL in the "initialPage"

Save the file, restart "gulp serve" and the workbench will open in your browser using http

Comment: Whoaw - that exactly helped, my workbench is working now. You made my day!!! @user1730 thanks a ton!

Comment: Possibly you missed adding Dev certificate using NPM. That was a part of the tutorial, that is why with https you were probably getting trust issues.

Comment: Thank you @mohdtahir - I had tried "gulp trust-dev-cert" before as well - but that did not fix the issue.

Comment: any other fix,it doesn't work for me

Comment: maybe setting NODE_NO_HTTP2=1 will help, see https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1002

Comment: see also the "Troubleshooting" section of the documentation https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment#troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

This can also be caused by something else on your system that uses port 5432.

This resolved the issue for me:

I changed the port number in config\serve.json.

In the screen shot below, I changed the `initialPage` port from 5432 to 5437.
I also changed the port in the api section to 5437.

I left port 4321 alone.

[image]